# Equality in Chebyshev's Inequality

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, probability-distributions

I need to show the following random variable results in equality for Chebyshev's inequality. However, I believe I am making some mistakes that I cannot find. Please help me spot my mistake.

$p \in (0,1), t \in \mathbb{R}, P(X=-t)=P(X=t)=p, P(X=0)=1-2p$

Chebyshev's inequality is said to be

$P(|X-E(X)|>t) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{t^2}, t >0$

I got

$E(X) = tp - tp +0 = 0$

$Var(X)= t^2p+(-t)^2p+0 = 2pt^2$

So $P(|X-E(X)|>t) = P(|X|>t) = 0 \ (\text{if t $\geq$ 0}) \neq 2p = \frac{Var(X)}{t^2}$

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your computations. It is called Chebychev's *in*equality and not Chebychev's equality. Chebychev's inequality gives you just an upper bound for $P(|X|>t)$. In your case, $P(|X|>t)=0$ and Chebychev's inequality gives you $P(|X|>t)\leq 2p$, which is no contradiction since $0\leq 2p$.

By the way, you have to additionally assume that $p\leq \frac{1}{2}$, in order for $P$ to be a probability measure ($P(X=0)=1-2p$ must be nonnegative, i.e., $p\leq \frac{1}{2}$).

Answer (score 0):

The Chebyshev Inequality is$$P(|X−E[X]|\color{red}\ge m)\le\frac{V[X]}{m^2}$$
For the same random variable, the RHS might be equal to the LHS for some value of $m$ and not equal for other values. For $m=t$,$$P(|X|\ge t)=P(X=t)+P(X=-t)=2p=\frac{V[X]}{t^2}$$Hence equality is achieved. But it is not achieved for $m>t$ or $0<m<t$, where inequality is strict.

Note that if I were to use your version of Chebychev Inequality,$$P(|X−E[X]|\color{red}>m)\le2p\left(\frac tm\right)^2$$equality would be nowhere achieved since$$P(|X|>m)=\begin{cases}2p,&0<m<t\\0,&m\ge t\end{cases}$$which doesn't intersect $2pt^2/m^2$ at any $m>0$.